# Pass filename between two functions

Tags: python, global-variables

I know the answer is probably trivial, but how can I pass a filename from a function to another? The filename is built in my function `the_reader` and I want to read it in my main function. I report both the functions below.

```
def the_reader(index, x, y, peak_number):
   [...]
   filename = ('file.txt')
   return filename
   mat_1 = np.array(mat,numpy.uint16)
   np.savetxt(filename, mat_1, fmt='%i')
```

Main function:

```
if __name__ == '__main__': 
   [...]
   the_reader(index, x, y, peak_number)
```

Then in the main if I type `print filename` I got the error: `NameError: name 'filename' is not defined`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the_reader() functions returns the filename variable, so if you `print(the_reader(index, x, y, peak_number))` you are printing the returned value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code. First, you should put return at the end of a function. When python encounters a return, it, well, returns and won't execute the lines that follow.

Second, you can't just return a value, you need to assign it to a variable in order to use it.

So the correct way would be:

```
def the_reader(index, x, y, peak_number):
   [...]
   filename = ('file.txt')
   mat_1 = np.array(mat,numpy.uint16)
   np.savetxt(filename, mat_1, fmt='%i')
   return filename

if __name__ == '__main__': 
   [...]
   filename = the_reader(index, x, y, peak_number)
```